# FaceBook Graph API

Tags: api, facebook

When I use FaceBook API for retrieving posts information, I found that the returned information are changing all the time.
 for e.g., when I retrieved information 2 times with 1mins interval, one record appears in the 1st time, and disapeared in the 2nd time.

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=baby&type=post&limit=100&since=2010-05-19&until=2010-05-21

Does anyone know what happen?

Cheers,
LingChen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searches of large datasets are (in general) nondeterministic.

Comment: I am agree with you, but any other possibilities?

Comment: If you agree they're nondeterministic, why are you surprised that you can get different results?